# Fill Null address based on the same owner in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Lets say I have a table of house cleaning service like this.

```
| Customer| House Address | Date     |
| ------- | ------------- | -------- |
| Sam     | London        | 10/01/22 |
| Lina    | Manchester    | 12/01/22 |
| Sam     | Null          | 15/01/22 |
```

We know that Sam house address should be **London** (assume that the customer id is the same).

How can I fill the third row based on the first row?

Data:

```
{'Customer': ['Sam', 'Lina', 'Sam'],
 'House Address': ['London', 'Manchester', nan],
 'Date': ['10/01/22', '12/01/22', '15/01/22']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `groupby` "Customer" and transform `first` for "House Address" (`first` drops NaN values so only London will be selected for Sam). It returns a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original `df` filled with the transformed firsts.

Then pass this to `fillna` to fill NaN values in "House Address":

```
df['House Address'] = df['House Address'].fillna(df.groupby('Customer')['House Address'].transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
  Customer House Address      Date
0      Sam        London  10/01/22
1     Lina        Sydney  12/01/22
2      Sam        London  15/01/22
```